# Is there any way to make a MapPolyline have better performance on WP7

Tags: silverlight, performance, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm currently using the Silverlight Map control for WP7, and am trying to visualize driving directions on the map. In order to highlight the route needed, I am using a `MapLayer` with a `MapPolyline`. The problem is that even with `CacheMode` set to `BitmapCache`, the MapPolyline area gets redrawn whenever the user pans or zooms the map. I've used other controls such as Ellipses or Pushpins, and with BitmapCache on, none of them redraw and give the same performance hit as MapPolyline.

Here's a quick example

```
    <maps:Map ZoomLevel="3">
        <maps:MapPolyline Name="line" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="9">
            <maps:MapPolyline.CacheMode>
                <BitmapCache/>
            </maps:MapPolyline.CacheMode>
            <maps:MapPolyline.Locations>
                <maps:LocationCollection>
                    <geo:GeoCoordinate Latitude="33" Longitude="33"/>
                    <geo:GeoCoordinate Latitude="36" Longitude="33"/>
                    <geo:GeoCoordinate Latitude="33" Longitude="36"/>
                </maps:LocationCollection>
            </maps:MapPolyline.Locations>
        </maps:MapPolyline>       
    </maps:Map>
```

If you set `App.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;` you can see the redrawing that occurs. The performance is particularly bad when you have a larger polyline and zoom in closer.

Is there anything that can be done to help? The native Bing Maps has pretty smooth route drawing, so I would think that there should be a way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a bit more what the problem is?

I've got an app - RunSat - in which I draw polylines with several hundred points (e.g. I just looked at a 3 hour long bike ride) and this draws fine - including during zoom operations.

I don't understand the problem - even using the sample code above. To help - are you testing on a phone or on the emulator?

As for CacheMode and BitmapCache, I'm really not sure about using these settings for the map - I don't use them in RunSat if that helps - I just leave the phone alone to work out its own GPU drawing.

Comment: I've been using test routes made up 1 large mappolyline (with a few hundred location points) and a dozen or two ellipse controls - typically when zooming in very close, the performance starts lagging - panning around seems to be ok. Following your model, I disabled BitmapCache and that actually helped - it is still somewhat laggy though. I guess since it was redrawing on every pan, it didnt make sense to cache the line (however bitmapcache does help perf with the ellipses).

Comment: If you want to improve performance another method is to reduce the detail level of your polyline - either through simple decimation or through a smarter algorithm like Douglas-Peucker

Comment: Since BitmapCache is a UIElement level API, it might be possible to enable/disable it for individual map components (but probably not going to help that much - sorry!)

Comment: I've found (at the cost of a little flickering) that if you set the Visibility of the MapPolyline to collapsed on the mapzoom event (and then Visible on ViewChangeEnd event) it performs a good amount better with a large point count. Also thanks for the reference of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm, going to try to implement that for different zoom levels :)